# Node - Delete an array of strings referenced to files

Tags: node.js, fs

In Angular I'm passing an array of strings with references to files that I want to delete:

```
let filesToDeleteOnCancel = ["file1.png", "file2.png", "file3.png"];

this.http.delete(this.apiDomain + '/api/gameCentre/deleteAssets', filesToDeleteOnCancel).subscribe((data: any) => {
  console.log(data);
}, error => {});
```

This appears to be working fine. But I'm getting confused on the node api as to how to pass this array in so I can delete the files. So far I have:

```
router.delete('/deleteAssets/', function(req, res) {
  console.log("How can I get the array here?");
  try {
    var files = ['../game/src/file1.png', '../game/src/file2.png', '../game/src/file3.png'];
    files.forEach(path => fs.existsSync(path) && fs.unlinkSync(path))
    // success code here
  } catch (err) {
    // error handling here
    console.error(err)
  }
});
```

Comment: Come on who will heed the call?! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your HTTP method to `POST` and send it via `body`. You can access the body as `req.body`. You may also need to use [Node.js body parsing middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html).

```
let filesToDeleteOnCancel = ['../game/src/file1.png', '../game/src/file2.png', '../game/src/file3.png'];

this.http.post(this.apiDomain + '/api/gameCentre/deleteAssets', filesToDeleteOnCancel).subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data);
}, error => { });

router.post('/deleteAssets/', function (req, res) {
    console.log("How can I get the array here?");
    try {
        var files = req.body;
        files.forEach(path => fs.existsSync(path) && fs.unlinkSync(path))
        // success code here
    } catch (err) {
        // error handling here
        console.error(err)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the request body like below:

`var files = req.body;`

And don`t forget about body-parser if the output is empty.